# How can I generate a path relative to a Javascript/jQuery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, relative-path

I have a CMS template that uses JavaScript/jQuery to insert an image onto the page.  This works fine when I specify an explicit path to the image, but because I use the template on several sites, the path needs to be determined automatically.

Making things a little harder is the fact that the path to the template (and therefore the image I'm linking to) changes periodically with each revision to the template.

Here's the (extremely simple) relevant code at the moment - which technically works in the short term, but is not the solution I'm looking for:-

```
src = '../template_v1/images/pdf_small.png'
```

This correctly generates the base URL, but breaks as soon as the template version is incremented (and the path changed) to `template_v2` or `template_v3`, for example.

The JavaScript/jQuery file (again, included with the template) is located at `http://www.domain.com/template_v1/js/this_file.js` - so with that in mind, I want to be able to automatically generate a path to the image relative to the location of the `this_file.js` file.  If this were CSS this would be easy, as non-explicit paths are relative to the CSS file calling the path - but I don't know how to accomplish this with JavaScript/jQuery.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in, blex.  I'm aware that that's an option - but it's not the solution I'm looking for.  I'm looking for a way for the path to be determined automatically so that updating the template doesn't break any links.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to go up a folder at the start of the source?  Would going from the current directory work and stay within the template folder entirely:

```
src = './images/pdf_small.png'
```

Comment: Hi James - thanks for the suggestion.  This doesn't work, however.  You are correct in that I need to go up a folder first (which would be '../images/pdf_small.png' - with two full stops) - but this is then relative to the root of the site - NOT relative to the file.  In CSS your suggestion would work - but not, it seems, in JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Yes - in this case the path is relative to the html page that's loaded the javascript file, unlike a stylesheet where it's relative to the stylesheet file itself